# How to use blockUI and Vue.js with v-el directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, blockui

I was wondering if there is anyway to use the plugin blockUI with Vue.js through v-el directive!

I would like to do something like:

```
this.$els.myElement.block();
this.$els.myElement.unblock();
```

Any clue or anything similar easier?

Comment: Couldn't you place a dummy div above your element and block this one instead of the VueJs one?

Comment: Yes I could! But I think the solution posted by @linus-borg is pretty good! What do you think? I think blockUI is good to use because you can block any element any time with only one command! I would like to use the v-el command because I want to manipulate it through Vue!

Comment: Oh, I thought Vue and BlockUI were incompatible because they were both modifying the innerHTML of the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(this.$els.myElement).block()
```